# What and where is -lsctpsocket?

Tags: c++, makefile, sctp

I'm working on an application that needs to support SCTP. Upon building a testing tool (Seagull) from source I cannot seem to find what the issue is. What is this flag (-lsctpsocket)? Is it a library? Where do I get it from?

Heres the command that the .mk file runes:

````
g++ -fPIC -shared /some_files.o -L./ext-1.8.3/lib -lsctplib -lsctpsocket -o /some_path/libtrans_extsctp.so```
````

Comment: `-l` means to link a library

Comment: `Is it a library?` Yes. `Where do I get it from?` I don't know.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot seem to find such a file even on machines where the tool is working properly. Is there a way to search for it (that is not case and extension sensitive)?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Don't look for `lsctpsocket` but do look for `sctpsocket`.  The `-l` part means link to this library.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Okay, found it. It seems that it exists and its in the right directory. But the tool can't seem to find it. Here's the error I get: ```[Linking /some_path/build-1.8.3/libtrans_extsctp.so]
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsctpsocket: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: Try adding `-L` followed by the directory it's found in (capital L)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso It didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Okay I figured that out. The path I was providing was incorrect. It compile and everything. After running the tool I get the following error: ```|E|Unable to open library file [libtrans_extsctp.so] error [/usr/local/bin/libtrans_extsctp.so: undefined symbol: ext_select]
```